# HtmlUnit modify outgoing request? how?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to modify a request made by HtmlUnit before it gets sent out, I did a lot of Googling and found this in their FAQ

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse

> How to modify the outgoing request or incoming response? You can
>   subclass HttpWebConnection and override getResponse() as:
>
> ```
>     new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
>
>         public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
>             WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
>             // modify the response by creating a new WebResponse
>             return response;
>         }
>     };
> ```

I'm trying to modify the request after clicking a submit button like the example below

```
page = submitButtonSend.click();
```

How should this be written so I can modify the outgoing request before it gets sent out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
    modifyRequest(request);
    return super.getResponse(request);
}
```

Comment: thanks but how do I pass it the requests which are made by this

page = submitButtonSend.click();

Comment: You don't pass it anything. The constructor of WebConnectionWrapper makes sure that every request sent by the WebClient passed as argument is sent using the wrapper.